# how to completely remove android and all its files from mac?

Tags: android, meteor, homebrew

Awhile ago I tried to get cordova working but the android emulator would never start. It just hangs with a black screen.

I had originally installed it with `brew install android-sdk`.

Then I read somewhere that was bad. So I have since removed it and installed Android Studio.

Either way, I could never get the emulator to bring up an app.

I have tried remove android studio by dragging to trash from Apps, but it seems to have left some files around.

I just recently tried running meteor which has a built in command for running/installing the android sdk, but alas, when I run the app there it just crashes too.

```
$ meteor run android
Starting android emulator
[[[[[ ~/projects/simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
Unexpected exit code 1 from /Users/username/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/tools/emulator [ '-avd', 'meteor' ]
stdout:
 emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg

emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context


stderr:
 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

I have no idea. I just need to start over I guess. iOS works fine.

Here is a screenshot from Android Studio when I try to run the emulator:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I had a VM running apparently. No idea how, but I restarted the computer and emulator boots up fine as long as I don't run any other apps.